# WebView broken in Android API 23 and below

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Lately, I have been in trouble running webviews on emulators with API 23 and below.

Webpages is running like this (same code): [API 29 and API 21, side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO1uH.png)

Already updated Android Studio and AVD manager, but the problem remains

My code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Just posted ;) thx

Answer (score 0):

try my code :

**in layout.xml :**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

---

**Activity.Java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

**NOTE**: do not forget to add **INTERNET** permission in your `manifest.xml` :